# python and XMLHttpRequest xml GET/POST

Tags: javascript, python, ajax

I'm having a lot of issues using python and XMLHttpRequest().

I am trying to press a button on a webpage, that button send a string to python using POST and pythons urllib2.

Firstly, on the index page fun1() is not defined. 
(i have about 6 identical pages with the same js and they work fine.)

python:

```
abc = urllib2.urlopen("http://0.0.0.0:3333/POST").read()
print(abc)
```

HTML index

```
<span class="button" onlick="jsfun1()"><p>button1</p></span>

<script type = text/javascript>
function jsfun1() {
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("POST", "/POST", true)
    xmlhttp.send("Hello World 1")
 }
```

html /POST is empty. as im not sure what to do here. I simply want it to hold a string until another POST is sent to it and then replace the string. Unless i can skip the /POST and receive it straight to the python code instead.

Using a flask server to create the webpages.

Comment: If it's not a class assignment, u might at least want to consider starting by exploring how existing minimal web servers in python would allow u to do this. I'd personally suggest Flask or Web.py

Comment: i already use Flask quite a lot (including in this example) and i have used webpy before however its functionality was a bit lacking for what i needed.  Also i have done a lot of searching before posting here, im just not sure what else i need to search for.